# Visual Studio - run unit tests on F5?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core

We have a team of developers working on a solution that has an ASP.net web project and 2 unit test projects. What happens is that developers develop the web project (and some underlyign layers), dev-test it via running the web project via F5, and then proceed to commit the changes. And sometimes these changes break the unit tests - which is found when the tests try to run on our build agent.

Is there a way to hook running unit tests when just "running" the web project (usually via F5)?

In another solution that had the same problem I wrote a cmd script as a post-build event for the web project. The script is ugly as it has to check that the build is running locally, and check that it's not stuck in a build-dependency loop.

Comment: well - you already have the solution. post build event.

Comment: Or use a commit strategy that involves pull requests: Devs can only push to branches, and branches can only be merged when the build on the CI passes.